# facebook cannot fetch user info with albums and photos

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

From graph api explorer I got this code for javascript sdk...

```
FB.login(function(response){ if (response.status === 'connected') {
FB.api(
      '/me',
      'GET',
      {"fields":"id,name,email,albums{name,cover_photo{source},photos{id,source}}"},
      function(response) {
         console.log(response)
      }
    );

}
```

but when I use this code it only gives me `id, email, name` field not albums.. How can I access albums too.. In graph explorer when I tried it is giving me all the albums with source and photos.

Comment: did you authorized with the correct permissions? (in that case, it would be user_photos). hard to say what´s wrong without more code.

Comment: without more code ? It is giving me email, id, and albums but not only albums.. If it is giving email, name and id then it should give albums and photos too right? In my graph explorer I am getting all the response

Comment: no, that´s wrong. it´s all about the permissions. most likely you did not authorize correctly. your login code would be important, and you should debug your access token.

Comment: `FB.login(function(response){
     
     if (response.status === 'connected') {// call api here}` this is my simple login function. and here I am getting `access_token` in my response

Comment: so where do you ask for the permissions? - btw, please don´t post code in comments, better edit your question so people don´t need to go through all comments to get all the information.